# What MPEG4 encoder library to use?

Tags: c++, directx, directshow, mpeg-4

So I have a WIN32 app that records videos using DirectShow. Now I want to convert the .AVI files to .MP4.

I rather not use a custom filter in the source, since I don't want to have to register filters(admin needed). I also dont want to use a standalone application since it should be automatised. Preferbly I just want a library with a well documented API since im rather new to this. Then I can use it from my app to convert the .AVI files when they are done being recorded. Anyone can point me in a direction? Or have comments on my method of choice?

I'd be outmost grateful for any help and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because MPEG-4 codecs are not royalty free, finding suitable encoder might be not as easy as you could think of it. Microsoft does not provide Windows with the encoder, except H.264 (MPEG-4 Part 10) encoder in some editions of Windows 7, and only within Media Foundation (as opposed to DirectShow). If you are OK to be limited to those Windows 7 versions, Media Foundation might be a good option, MSDN offers samples to transcode file into file and it is reasonably easy and well documented.

There are third party solutions, there half made libraries you can leverage to encoder, there is FFmpeg which offers MPEG-4 Part 2 video encoder under LGPL, and MPEG-4 Part 10 through libx264 under GPL. And my understanding you might still be expected to pay royalties to MPEG-LA. FFmpeg might still be a good option to convert file to file because its command lnie interface is well documented (as opposed to libavformat/libavcodec API which are not so well documented on the contrary).

Another option is to use Windows Media codecs and compress into ASF/WMV files.

Comment: Remember, if convert a video to some MPEG type, you need to pay royalitie to the MPEG LA! The same apllies to the audio in this video. If you can convert the audio-stream to AAC you need to pay royalities to the VIA Licening!

Comment: @CPlusSharp: Yes, with perhaps the only exception of Windows 7 where encoders are already present as a part of Windows (and Microsoft paid the royalties). However as I said, those are Media Foundation objects only.

Comment: It seems it was quite troublesome yes, Do royaltie fees apply to non comercial software too? And thanks again Roman for your well detailed answer.

Comment: @RomanR. If I remember correctly Mircosoft stated somewhere that the encoders can only be legaly used in Mircosoft products?

Comment: @CPlusSharp: As far as I remember this is the case of Dolby audio codecs ("Field of Use" restrictions on MSDN). Microsoft MPEG-4 encoders on the other hand are not limited in use, but only available via Media Foundation API (not DirectShow).

Comment: It looks like this actually can be done without royalties, thanks to Cisco's precompiled and royalty-free binaries: https://github.com/cisco/openh264

Comment: @PeterEhrlich: No, this is incorrect. The implementation is free, however this does not cover MPEG license fee. See their ["We will **not** pass on our MPEG-LA licensing costs for this module..."](http://www.openh264.org/). Thanks for the link anyway.

Comment: @RomanR. Not passing on costs means that they eat the cost.  As the quote continues: ".. this will effectively make H.264 free for use on supported platforms"

Comment: Their blog post has another wording for this: "... this will effectively make H.264 free **for use in WebRTC**". My understanding is that it's free only where MPEG-LA waived the licensing fees, and not totally free.

Comment: On the other hand, Mozilla announcement says another thing: "...  enables any open source project to incorporate Cisco’s H.264 module without paying MPEG LA license fees... and Cisco will pay for the patent license from the MPEG LA..."

Comment: Why WebRTC caveat makes a difference here? Because ["MPEG LA's AVC License Will Not Charge Royalties for Internet Video that is Free to End Users through Life of License"](http://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20100825006629/en/MPEG-LA%E2%80%99s-AVC-License-Charge-Royalties-Internet#.VDDf5cnzlbw). That is, not charging for free internet video and free Cisco implementation - together this makes it free H.264 encoder for internet video. Not totally free through in general sense for any H.264 video encoding task (as this question asks).

Answer (score 1):

Libavcodec and libffmpeg -- an everything-to-everything media converter (includes library and command-line application): http://ffmpeg.org/